# Redirect subdomain to subdomain on new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, domain, subdomain

I own 2 domains sio-india.org and sio-india.com

What i want to do is redirect all the subdomains from 1st domain to 2nd domain. eg. home.sio-india.org to home.sio-india.com
but i dont want to redirect sio-india.org to sio-india.com 
and also dont want to redirect www.sio-india.org to www.sio-india.com

Please help

I am using this code in htaccess but it is not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sio-india\.org$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1sio-india.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please hepl me I am stuck.

Comment: Are any redirects working? I.e. is the web server set up to respect rewrites defined in .htaccess?

Comment: So to summarize: redirect: `//home.sio-india.org` to `//home.sio-india.com`; Leave `//sio-india.org` alone; Leave `//sio-india.com` alone. Any other variations? What about `www` variations? And do all these sites live in the same webroot?

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to specify how exactly is it not working. It seems to me that your code would redirect everything (including http://sio-india.org). This is because .* means "any character, zero or more repetitions", so sio-india.org would match too.

You should change your condition to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.sio-india\.org$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.sio-india.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If that doesn't fix it - please be more specific about how it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks it works perfecttly! I am using it on one of my sites. Was looking for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But, the following solution worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.your-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.another-domain.com/ [R,L]
```

Too late to post. But, just wanted to share so that this can be helpful to other people.